# Сервер для аутентификации

Tags: c#, аутентификация, безопасность

Хочу добавить в своё приложение аутентификацию для пользователей.

Систему вижу такой:
При запуске приложения пользователю показывается форма, куда он вводит логин и пароль, потом посылается пароль на сервер, и если такие логин/пароль есть в базе - с сервера приходит положительный ответ.

Необходимо также, чтобы у пользователя была возможность создать пользователя, но так, чтобы его должен был бы подтвердить администратор сервера.

Хотелось бы, чтобы общение с сервером велось через https и была возможность использовать свой сертификат.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, существуют ли подобные решения или нужно городить свой велосипед?

Answer (score 1):

[VK Api.](https://vk.com/dev/sites)